# Why Do My Refresh Tokens Expire in 1 Hour?

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-api, refresh-token

I'm encountering an issue where my refresh token expires after an hour, and attempting to generate an access token with the expired refresh token results in an 'invalid_token' error message.
I've confirmed that the user hasn't revoked my app's access, changed their password, or exceeded the maximum number of granted refresh tokens, and my project is in production. I'm unsure why the refresh token is expiring so quickly and would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

I am using a curl command to obtain a refresh token from an OAuth2 service. I then use this refresh token to generate an access token, which has a lifespan of one hour.

When attempting to generate another access token using the same refresh token after an hour is passed, I get :

```
{ 
  "error": "invalid_token", 
  "error_description": "Token expired or revoked" 
}
```

Comment: refresh tokens don't expire after an hour access tokens do.  Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: That is my problem here though. Once my access token is expired (after one hour) I request another access token, and the way to obtain the new access token is by using your refresh token. However I get "Token expired or revoked"

Comment: There are a number of reasons a refresh token would expire if it has you should have the user authorize the application again.